# Java Hbase API throws RetriesExhaustedException when writing JUnit Tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, hadoop, hbase, microservices

im trying to write JUnit for the following method, which works perfectly when Im executing the method normally, but while invoking the Unit tests, it throws RetriesExhaustedException in **result.get()**.

Method to be Tested:

```
    @Override
public Event findEvents(String id) throws IOException {
    Table eventsTable = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    Event event = null;
    boolean iFlag = false;
    boolean aFlag = false;
    boolean fFlag = false;
    try {
        connection = connectionPool.get();
        eventsTable = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(configuration.getEventsTable()));
        Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(id.replaceAll(STRPATTERN, "")));
        Result r = eventsTable.get(g);// Exception occurs throwing RetiresExhaustedException
        if (!r.isEmpty()) { 
            event = genericRowRowMapperMapper.mapEventDetails(r, HbaseConstants.getEventheaderCf1(),
                    HbaseConstants.getEventbodyCf1(), iFlag, aFlag, fFlag);
            Util.replaceAid(event, id);
        }

    } finally {
        CGUtil.closeTable(eventsTable);
        releaseConnection(connection);
    }
    return event;
}
```

Test Method:

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void findEventsTest() throws Exception {

    String flexid = "25652365";
    Map<String, Event> eventMapF = new HashMap<>();
    Event eventF = new Event();
    Activity activityF = new Activity();
    activityF.setId("25652365");
    eventF.setActivity(activityF);
    eventMapF.put("25652365", eventF);

    Event evF = hBaseRepository.findEvents(flexid);
    assertNull(evF);
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=3, exceptions:
Wed Jan 08 12:35:36 IST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1578467135791, pause=1000, retries=3}, java.lang.AssertionError
Wed Jan 08 12:35:37 IST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1578467135791, pause=1000, retries=3}, java.lang.AssertionError
Wed Jan 08 12:35:40 IST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1578467135791, pause=1000, retries=3}, java.lang.AssertionError
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:867)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:832)
at com.citi.gcb.cg.repository.HbaseNativeRepository.findEvents(HbaseNativeRepository.java:103)
at com.citi.gcg.cg.repository.HbaseNativeRepositoryTests.findEventsTest(HbaseNativeRepositoryTests.java:143)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:19)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.loadCache(ClientScanner.java:484)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:312)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1327)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1224)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1208)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1165)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getRegionLocation(ConnectionManager.java:997)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HRegionLocator.getRegionLocation(HRegionLocator.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionServerCallable.prepare(RegionServerCallable.java:87)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:140)
```

I tried changing the increasing rpc timeout property from hbase-site.xml file but still the test case is not passing, its throwing the same exception.

Comment: For testing purpose u need runtime local HBase environment. follow this utility specially designed for HBase Testing (HBaseTestingUtility) ,  
https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-examples/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/example/TestAsyncClientExample.java

Comment: I tried using the same but the Result r = eventsTable.get(g); is still throwing an exception due to which assertequals is not working.